# PHP process to Bootstrap

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, flat

I'm working on a website HTML5. Is a landing page with a slideshow + iframe + content + footer.

On the iframe I have a PHP Process to login and complete forms.

This website I want to use it on iPad like a webview so the website is corectly show all content with flat design perfectly responsive, but on the iframe of PHP process the buttons are old design a classic html.

I want somehow to integrate bootstrap to have a diferent look like flat design so all buttons or design to be with the new look of the boostrap.

What shoult I do to have a diferent look. What files or scripts I have to integrate? 
These scripts have to be only on index.PHP ? or in all process form like.
not_loged.php , loged_in.php , process_1.php , process_2.php , finished_process.php.

Comment: If i'm reading your question correctly, it seems it could be simplified to: How do I use css?

Answer (score 0):

Twitter Bootstrap is simply a very comprehensive CSS and JS "theme" that is completely customisable. It is very helpful in development because we don't have to worry about conflicts between styles from JavaScript plugins and styles from our own CSS as it is all consistent

To use it, you just need to reference the CSS and JS files then start creating your layout or customise one of the examples provided. Also you won't need to create separate desktop and mobile pages because Bootstrap is fully responsive.

You can still edit page and others are untouched and the steps to convert your site would be to look at the documentation to find the layout options and the styles for certain elements you need. If you haven't already found it the documentation is found at http://www.getbootstrap.com.

***Reference:*** [Converting existing WebPages site to Twitter bootstrap](http://forums.asp.net/t/1930623.aspx?Converting+existing+WebPages+site+to+Twitter+bootstrap+how+).

Answer (score 0):

For every page you need to load your CSS-files. What you can do, if include al the links in a link-file, like `links.html`.

Fill it with the links to the CSS and JavaScript, like this:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Add custom CSS here -->
<link href="css/modern-business.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- JavaScript -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/modern-business.js"></script>
```

Then link to the file with `<?php include 'links.html'?>`

Better yet, if you have a header, then you can make an header.html with als the sheets and scripts loaded.